# Ethereum private blockchain empty blocks mining

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I have set up a private block chain with 2 nodes 1 being a miner node . However we are seeing lots of empty blocks being mined . i tried the solution suggested at this link https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/how-to-make-miner-to-mine-only-when-there-are-pending-transactions .
But still the empty blocks are mined . Can someone help ?

OS used - Windows 10
Ethereum version - 1.7.3 stable

I was unable to comment on the ethereum stackexchange thread due to lack of reputation

Comment: Hey, did you figure it out? I've the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Empty blocks are added by miners in order to avoid double spending.
It mainly avoids miner from doing POW for a already mined transaction. Only when the miner finds the transaction that was mined before, he will avoid adding empty blocks, else he adds them.